# Select the value of this id of dynamic of same id name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I select the id (which have the same id number but it fetches dynamically) it shows the first id value. I am using it like below but it doesn't work

```js
function editdr() {
  qty = $(this), ('#p1').val();
  alert(qty);
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <input id='p1' value>
  <button type="button" onclick="editdr()">Edit</button>
</tr>
<tr>
  <input id='p1' value>
  <button type="button" onclick="editdr()">Edit</button>
</tr>
<tr>
  <input id='p1' value>
  <button type="button" onclick="editdr()">Edit</button>
</tr>
<tr>
  <input id='p1' value>
  <button type="button" onclick="editdr()">Edit</button>
</tr>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Work but it shows this error:

```
>"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 19,
"colno": 14
```

Comment: You have multiple `input` with same id; id is supposed to be unique

Comment: Include jQuery, then $ issue will be resolved, plus multiple inputs with the same IDs

Comment: @NotABot dear its still error on selecting id value

Comment: @Dario dear look at code the cant fetch the same value

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanRajpotzada What is exactly your question? PS - Already said you don't have jQuery and also you cannot have multiple inputs with the same IDs. Also ``$(this), ('#p1').val();`` what you want here? You are using comma(,)

Comment: select the value of multiple row id  but it cant do this

Comment: This line does not seem syntatically correct `qty = $(this),('#p1').val();  `

Comment: i have 4 row of input and button field which come dynamic i want when i click on edit button of row then show the same id value which i click of the row

Comment: @NotABot okay but I remove the comma but it cant take value

Comment: when I change comma into. dotte it said it's undefined

Comment: Ids should/need to be unique on a page!

Answer (score 0):

There were a few points in your script/markup that needed fixing. Here is my version of a working page:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  qty = $(this).closest("tr").find("input:last").val();
  console.log(qty);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td><input id='p1' value="one"></td><td></td><td><button type="button">Edit</button></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id='pxtra' value="xtra"></td>
    <td><input id='p2' value="two"></td><td><button type="button">Edit</button></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id='p3' value="three"></td><td></td><td><button type="button">Edit</button></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id='p4' value="four"></td><td></td><td><button type="button">Edit</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

**Update**

There are many ways of addressing individual input elements within one row. In my example above I used the `:last` attribute in the css selector, but you could also do something like `.eq(1)`, `.eq(2)` etc. ...

However, using an actual `id` as an identifier often makes programming more complicated than it is helpful.

Comment: sir its correct but when i use two or three input field in same td then how i take the value